# Is the precision of Thread.Sleep still poor?

Tags: c#, windows, thread-sleep, windows-server-2016

I was under the impression that `Thread.Sleep(x)` is not precise and that all it will do is sleep the thread for at *minimum* `x`ms. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508208/what-is-the-impact-of-thread-sleep1-in-c/522681#522681), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254703/thread-sleep-for-less-than-1-millisecond) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066900/thread-sleep1-takes-longer-than-1ms).

When sleeping for a very low amount of time, e.g. `1ms`, it is expected that you will find that the thread occasionally sleeps for about `15ms`. This is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067000/596841) due to clock interrupt rate which by default is `64` times per second.

I tried this a couple of years ago and indeed, I too experienced the `15ms` resolution. However, I have just tried again and now I am seeing `1ms` to `2ms` resolution with very rarely > 2ms.

What has changed? Has .NET changed (I'm using `4.6` at the moment, don't remember what I used 2 years ago)? Perhaps it is the operating system which has changed? (I used and am still using AWS EC2 Windows Server, but perhaps there has been an update.)

My simple test program:

```
private static Stopwatch sw =new Stopwatch();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    var results = new List<long>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        timer.Restart();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        results.Add(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    foreach (var item in results.Where(x => x > 1).ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item );
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: What else do you have going on your computer at the time of testing? That will likely effect timings.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Nothing at the moment - perhaps that is why I am seeing pretty high precision?

Comment: My favorite is when I see people trying to sleep for 1 microsecond...

Comment: Search for `timebeginperiod` here on SO if you're not familiar with its affect on `Sleep` and others.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `timebeginperiod` is mentioned a few times in the posts I've linked. I am asking if the precision of `Thread.Sleep` has changed as I am now getting high precision. I think @Carcigenicate has a good point though - perhaps I should test when I have a CPU intensive task running in the background.

Comment: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

Comment: *"A"* (as in, "any") CPU-intensive task won't inherently make Thread.Sleep have the behavior described.

Comment: Run powercfg.exe /energy from an elevated command prompt to find the evildoer.  If you use Chrome then you don't have to look, freeware from a company that has a big stake in battery-powered devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precision of `Thread.Sleep` (and the underlying Windows API `Sleep` function in kernel32) is dependent on the resolution of the system clock, **which has a default tick rate of roughly 15 ms**. Applications can request a higher resolution, in which case *the highest requested resolution is used globally*.

In this case case, you're likely seeing sub-15 ms resolution because something running on your system has requested a higher resolution.

If your application actually needs sub-15 ms sleeps, it can request a higher resolution via the native [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) function.

However, note that it is possible that the underlying timer device won't support your requested resolution, so it's not good practice to write code that relies on this behavior unless you're absolutely sure of the hardware your code will be running on.

Comment: The native system calls in ntdll.dll are `NtQueryTimerResolution(PULONG MaximumTime, PULONG MinimumTime, PULONG CurrentTime)` and `NtSetTimerResolution(ULONG DesiredTime, BOOLEAN SetResolution, PULONG ActualTime)`, using 100 ns time units. Also, of the winmm.dll functions, note that [`timeGetTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime) is updated according to the real timer resolution, as opposed to `GetTickCount`, which seems to use a count that's hard-coded to update every 15.625 ms, regardless of the real resolution.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Thanks. I have noticed that if I fire up a bunch of YouTube videos, I start to see more wild measurements where `Thread.Sleep(x)` sleeps longer than `x` about 10% of the time.