# My playback is lagging with midioutshortmsg

Tags: c#, wpf, midi

I Use Wpf.
I parse a midi file and use midioutshortmsg to send message in a For Loop,
and sleep for delay Delta Time;
My playback is lagging ,But, when i open other midi software at the same time
(include WindowMediaPlayer) ,All the Problem is sloved,My Program work fine.
When I close the other opened software.Problem is come back.

My program stuck in here.
I have already to try send in midistreamout,MidiOutProc,or midioutlongmsg,etc.but my problem still can't solve.
Thank You Very Much.

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private extern static int midiOutOpen(out int lphMidiOut, int uDeviceID, int dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public extern static int midiOutShortMsg(int lphMidiOut, int dwMsg);

public int midiOut;

private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
midiOutOpen(out midiOut, 0, 0, 0, 0);

InstanceCaller = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendMessage));
InstanceCaller.Start();
}

private void SendMessage()
{
for (int i = 0; i < melodyList.Count; i++)
{
var messgae = Convert.ToInt32(melodyList[i], 16);
midiOutShortMsg(midiOut, messgae);
Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(durationList[i]));
}
}
```

Comment: whay are you sleeping durationlist[i] can you debug and see what those values are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread.Sleep(1) takes longer than 1ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066900/thread-sleep1-takes-longer-than-1ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with Windows, you can use [winmm timer functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timer-reference) to run high-resolution timer which will give 1ms precision, which impossible with `Thread.Sleep`.

Also you can use third-party libraries, which do all this job for you. I'm the author of [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) so you can use it for playback. Please read [Playback](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html) article os the library docs to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim .I try winmm timer,it can solve my problem.But use DryWetMIDI is more easy and convenient.Thanks.